# Sharpening a knife as N"T

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

Is sharpening a knife a concern of Nothein Ta'am in Kashruth matters?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25898/5

Comment: You mean to/from the knife and sharpener?

Comment: Near-duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13462